# How to set Your antivirus as Window's default antivirus program?

Tags: wfp

I have developed an Antivirus software, however how do I set it as the default Antivirus and make Windows stop displaying the missing Antivirus messages?

Comment: Read somewhere that you had to sign an NDA with Microsoft and use a private API that they provide. I'll look for the link - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb190942(v=vs.85).aspx points to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb190942%28v=vs.85%29.aspx. - Can't comment on if this information is outdated or not.

Comment: That information is still accurate.

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: @Braiam do you realize editing a years old bad question sends it back to the top of the queue?

Comment: @GeorgeJempty so it can be closed promply? Of course I know. BTW, there was ([is still](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31187140/792066)) a spam answer that bumped the question before my edit...

Answer (score 0):

You should add it to the Security Center inside the windows, but I'm not sure that maybe you need a digital signature.